# Return a value if a condition is met via VBA

Tags: excel, vba, conditional-statements

I have code that goes through a source xls file and based on the company name pull out sales data relevant to that company and populate it in the company's own file.

It works, but I want to only return a value in one of my columns if a condition is met.

It's the commented line in the code below.

```vb
For i = 2 To LastRow
       
    If SourceSheet.Cells(i, 21).Value Like "CompanyName goes here*" Then
 
        'change the column numbers to the relevant number
        Product = SourceSheet.Cells(i, 11).Value
        Base Sales Value = SourceSheet.Cells(i, 27).Value 
        Partner = SourceSheet.Cells(i, 21).Value
        EndUser = SourceSheet.Cells(i, 7).Value
        License = SourceSheet.Cells(i, 13).Value
        PostingMonth = SourceSheet.Cells(i, 3).Value
        LicType = SourceSheet.Cells(i, 12).Value
        newuplift = SourceSheet.Cells(i, 15).Value
        UpliftValue = SourceSheet.Cells(i, 28).Value

        erow = DestSheet.Cells(DestSheet.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).Row
             
        'change the column numbers to the relevant number
        DestSheet.Cells(erow, 1).Value = ProdType
        DestSheet.Cells(erow, 2).Value = License
        DestSheet.Cells(erow, 3).Value = Partner
        DestSheet.Cells(erow, 4).Value = EndUser
        DestSheet.Cells(erow, 5).Value = SOValue
        DestSheet.Cells(erow, 6).Value = PostingMonth
        DestSheet.Cells(erow, 7).Value = newuplift
        DestSheet.Cells(erow, 8).Value = LicType
        DestSheet.Cells(erow, 9).Value = UpliftValue 'TRYING TO PLACE A CONDITION HERE - SEE BELOW

        ' If newuplift = "Renewal" then place the Upliftvalue in row 9, otherwise set to "0"
               
    End If
    
Next i
```

Comment: Perhaps `If newuplift = "Renewal" Then DestSheet.Cells(erow, 9).Value = UpliftValue Else DestSheet.Cells(erow, 9).Value = 0` ?

Comment: _then place the Upliftvalue in row 9_ do you mean column 9 ? Note you have "Product" v "ProdType" and "Base Sales Value" v "SOValue"

Answer (score 1):

You could use `IIf()`

```
DestSheet.Cells(erow, 9).Value = IIf(newuplift = "Renewal", UpliftValue, 0)
```

Comment: sadly this returned a component not optional error, but the solution posted earlier sorted it - thanks all

Comment: This works fine for me and is functionally equivalent to what CLR suggested.